# Bridge game individual movement split between "Pro"s and "Am"s

Tags: duplicate-bridge

I'm interested in whether anyone knows of bridge movements for individual events in which the players are split (by experience) into "pro"s and "am"s. Thus in each partnership there is a pro player and an am player.

I'm aware of collections of individual movements, but none of them seems to enforce this split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Rainbow* movements](http://www.baronbarclay.com/rainbow) have individuals remaining a single direction, but only work for a number of tables that is a prime number. If you had 'Pros' sitting North and East, and 'Ams' sitting South and West, then you can also switch partners once each round. My copy of **Duplicate Bridge Direction** by *Alex Groner* (1977)  describes these in ***Chapter 7*** and lists detailed movements for several possible table numbers in ***Appendix F***

[The Bridge Guys](http://www.bridgeguys.com/Conventions/movements_for_bridge.html) provide sample table cards for numerous movements, including  [a 5 table Rainbow Individual Movement](http://www.bridgeguys.com/pdf/Movements/IN/20_player_individual_guide_card_20_30boards.pdf) .